# Cannot import xlwings on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, xlwings

I'm new in Python world and have a problem to import xlwings on PyCharm.

I have installed Python 3.5 and anaconda as well. Anaconda shows me that xlwings installed successfully and have the same result on pip. In project interpreter PyCharm I can see xlwings 0.7.2 but I get error and cannot install it.

Comment: If it's listed in the project interpreter then it should be installed. How are you importing it?

Comment: no it's not in the project interpreter, but when I add that from the search windows in comes with the error * copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/psutil/tests
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.*
I have installed as pip install xlwings  and it's succeed. also from anaconda I installed it and it was succeeded as well.
    
    
    
    
    Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
    
    
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 69

Answer (score 0):

I made this:
For example, you have a workbook named "Book1" in your current working directory. Then:

```
from xlwings import Range, Workbook
wb_name = "Book1"
Workbook.set_mock_caller(wb_name)
wb = Workbook.caller()
print(Range(1, 'A1').value)
```

You can made that. I had installed Anaconda and PyCharm and for my it's good.